# Defining unit and counit for the adjunction between $\mathbf{Grp}$ and $\mathbf{Ab}$

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

So I'm trying to write the proof for the following example of adjunction as training for an upcoming exam and I can't for the love of God figure this out. Here are the details.

I have the following functors $F \colon \mathbf{Grp} \rightarrow \mathbf{Ab}$ (free functor) and $U \colon \mathbf{Ab} \rightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$ (inclusion functor).

[image: Action of the functors F and U.]

I have the unit and counit written out too (which I hope I wrote right):

- $\eta \colon \mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{Grp}} \Rightarrow U \circ F$ aka $\eta_A : A \rightarrow (U \circ F)(A)$,
- $\epsilon \colon F \circ U \Rightarrow \mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{Ab}}$ aka $\epsilon_{A_{\mathrm{ab}}} \colon F(A) \rightarrow A_{\mathrm{ab}}$,
- plus the triangular diagrams (I didn't include them here).

I'm trying to use the triangular identities to write the proof, but I'm stuck at the point where I need to define the unit and counit in order to proceed with the rest of the proof. If I were working with list, I'd write something like $\eta_{A} (a) = [a],$ but it's not list I'm working with.

Could someone explain it to me how I should proceed?

Comment: You write $A$ in place of $F$ several times. Also, what is $A_{ab}$? And, can you describe what $F$ is, i.e. what is a '*free Abelian group over a group $G$*'?

Comment: My bad, I corrected the Fs. $A_{ab}$ is a notation I made for an abelian group A. F is the covariant functor.

Comment: @Berci Presumably they refer to the adjoint functor giving the Abelianisation of a group

Comment: @FShrike yeah, that. Sorry it's 1 am and my brain is failing me.

Comment: I'm confused. When you say "I have the unit and counit... plus the triangle identities", are you saying you have already constructed $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ and show the identities? Or do you mean you want to construct these and derive the identities?

Comment: And, one way of deriving the unit and counit is from the bijection $Hom(F(G), A)\cong Hom(G, U(A))$ and looking at where $1_F(G)$ and $1_U(A)$ are sent, respectively. Do you already have this set bijection?

Answer (score 2):

## Basics on abelianization

Let us recall how abelianization works:

- For every group $G$, its abelianization $\newcommand{\ab}{\mathrm{ab}} G^{\ab}$ is the quotient $G / [G, G]$ where $[G, G]$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$.
- We have for every group $G$ the homomorphism of groups
  $$
    \newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
    p_G \colon G \longto G^{\ab} \,, \quad g \longmapsto [g] \,,
  $$
  which is the *canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $G^{\ab}$*.
- The group $G^{\ab}$ together with the homomorphism $p_G$ satisfies the following universal property:
  given an abelian group $A$, every homomorphism of groups $φ$ from $G$ to $A$ factors uniquely through $p_G$.
  More explicitly, there exists for every homomorphism of groups $φ$ from $G$ to $A$ a unique homomorphism of groups $ψ$ from $G^{\ab}$ to $A$ with $φ = ψ ∘ p_G$.
- The abelianization construction $(-)^{\ab}$ is functorial:
  for every homomorphism $φ$ from $G$ to $H$ there exists a unique homomorphism of groups $φ^{\ab}$ from $G^{\ab}$ to $H^{\ab}$ that makes the following diagram commute:
  $$
    \require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
      G           @> φ >>         H          \\
      @V p_G VV                   @VV p_H V \\
      G^{\ab}     @>> φ^{\ab} >   H^{\ab}
    \end{CD}
    \tag{$\ast$}
  $$
  (As a formula, $p_H ∘ φ = φ^{\ab} ∘ p_G$.)
  The homomorphism $φ^{\ab}$ is explicitly given by
  $$
    φ^{\ab}
    \colon
    G^{\ab} \longto H^{\ab} \,,
    \quad
    [g] \longmapsto [φ(g)] \,.
  $$

Let us check in the following that the abelianization functor $F := (-)^{\ab}$ from $\newcommand{\Grp}{\mathbf{Grp}} \Grp$ to $\newcommand{\Ab}{\mathbf{Ab}} \Ab$ is left-adjoint to the forgetful functor $U$ from $\Ab$ to $\Grp$.

## Via natural bijection of $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}} \Hom$-sets

The universal property of the abelianization gives us for every group $G$ and every abelian group $A$ a bijection
$$
  Φ_{G, A}
  \colon
  \Hom_{\Ab}(G^{\ab}, A) \longto \Hom_{\Grp}(G, A) \,,
  \quad
  ψ \longmapsto ψ ∘ p_G \,.
$$
In other words, a bijection
$$
  Φ_{G, A} \colon \Hom_{\Ab}(F(G), A) \longto \Hom_{\Grp}(G, U(A)) \,.
$$
This bijection is natural in both $G$ and $A$, and therefore gives an adjunction
$$
  F ⊣ U \,.
$$

So how do the unit $η$ and counit $ε$ of this adjunction look like?
Let us recall the general construction:

- Suppose we have an adjunction $F ⊣ U$ between two functors $\newcommand{\cat}{\mathscr} F \colon \cat{C} \to \cat{D}$ and $U \colon \cat{D} \to \cat{C}$, given by bijections
  $$
    Φ_{X, Y} \colon \Hom_{\cat{D}}(F(X), Y) \longto \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, U(Y)) \,.
  $$
  The unit $η$ and counit $ε$ are then natural transformations
  $$
    η \colon \mathrm{Id}_{\cat{C}} \Longrightarrow U F \,,
    \quad
    ε \colon F U \Longrightarrow \mathrm{Id}_{\cat{D}}.
  $$
- For every object $X$ of $\cat{C}$, the component $η_X$ is a morphism from $X$ to $UF(X)$.
  Under the bijection
  $$
    Φ_{X, F(X)}
    \colon
    \Hom_{\cat{D}}(F(X), F(X)) \longto \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, UF(X)) \,,
  $$
  the morphism $η_X$ corresponds to $\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}} \id_{F(X)}$.
- For every object $Y$ of $\cat{D}$, the component $ε_Y$ is a morphism from $FU(Y)$ to $Y$.
  Under the bijection
  $$
    Φ_{U(Y), Y}
    \colon
    \Hom_{\cat{D}}(FU(Y), Y) \longto \Hom_{\cat{C}}(U(Y), U(Y)) \,,
  $$
  the morphism $ε_Y$ corresponds to $\id_{U(Y)}$.

In our specific example, this means the following:

- For every group $G$, the component $η_G$ is a homomorphism of groups from $G$ to $UF(G) = G^{\ab}$.
  It is the image of $\id_{G^{\ab}}$ under the bijection
  $$
    Φ_{G, G^{\ab}}
    \colon
    \Hom_{\Ab}(G^{\ab}, G^{\ab}) \longto \Hom_{\Grp}(G, G^{\ab}) \,,
    \quad
    ψ \longmapsto ψ ∘ p_G \,.
  $$
  Therefore, $η_G = p_G$ is the canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $G^{\ab}$.
  In formulas, we have
  $$
    η_A
    \colon
    A \longto A^{\ab} \,,
    \quad
    a \longmapsto [a] \,.
  $$
- For every abelian group $A$, the component $ε_A$ is a homomorphism of groups from $FU(A) = A^{\ab}$ to $A$.
  Under the bijection
  $$
    Φ_{A, A}
    \colon
    \Hom_{\Ab}(A^{\ab}, A) \longto \Hom_{\Grp}(A, A) \,,
    \quad
    ψ \longmapsto ψ ∘ p_A \,.
  $$
  the homomorphism $ε_A$ corresponds to $\id_A$.
  In other words, we have $ε_A ∘ p_A = \id_A$.
  The homomorphism $ε_A$ is therefore given by
  $$
    ε_A
    \colon
    A^{\ab} \longto A \,,
    \quad
    [a] \longmapsto a \,.
  $$

## Via triangle identities

We can also use the universal property of the abelianization to first construct $η$ and $ε$, and then check that the triangle identities are satisfied:

- We already have for every group $G$ a special homomorphism from $G$ to $G^{\ab}$, namely the canonical homomorphism $p_G$.
  So let $η_G := p_G$, i.e.,
  $$
    η_G \colon G \longto G^{\ab} \,, \quad g \longmapsto [g] \,.
  $$
  We need to check that these homomorphisms assemble into a natural transformation $η$ from $\mathrm{Id}_{\Grp}$ to $U ∘ F$.
  To this end, we need to check that for every homomorphism of groups $φ \colon G \to H$ the following diagram commutes.
  $$
    \require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
      G           @> φ >>         H          \\
      @V η_G VV                   @VV η_H V  \\
      G^{\ab}     @>> φ^{\ab} >   H^{\ab}
    \end{CD}
    \tag{$\ast$}
  $$
  But this is precisely the commutative diagram $(\ast)$ from the first section of this post.
- We need for every abelian group $A$ a homomorphism $ε_A$ from $A^{\ab}$ to $A$.
  By the universal property of the abelianization $A^{\ab}$, the desired homomorphism $ε_A \colon A^{\ab} \to A$ corresponds to a homomorphism $A \to A$. There is an obvious homomorphism $A \to A$, namely the identity homomorphism, so we choose $ε_A$ as the corresponding homomorphism from $A^{\ab}$ to $A$.
  More explicitly,
  $$
    ε_A \colon A^{\ab} \longto A \,, \quad [a] \longmapsto a \,.
  $$
  We need to check that the resulting transformation $ε$ from $UF$ to $\mathrm{Id}_{\Ab}$ is natural.
  In other words, we need to check that for every homomorphism of abelian groups $ψ \colon A \to B$ the following diagram commutes:
  $$
    \require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
      A^{\ab}      @> ψ^{\ab} >>   B^{\ab}    \\
      @V ε_A VV                    @VV ε_B V  \\
      A            @>> ψ >         B
    \end{CD}
    \tag{$\ast$}
  $$
  This holds true because
  $$
    ε_B( ψ^{\ab}( [a] ) ) = ε_B( [ψ(a)] ) = ψ(a) = ψ( ε_A( [a] ) ) \,.
  $$

Now that we have constructed the natural transformations $η$ and $ε$, we check that they satisfy the two triangle identities
$$
  εF ∘ Fη = \id_F
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  Uε ∘ ηU = \id_U \,.
$$

- For every group $G$ we have
  \begin{align*}
    (εF ∘ Fη)_G( [g] )
    &= ε_{G^{\ab}}( (η_G)^{\ab}( [g] ) ) \\
    &= ε_{G^{\ab}}( [η_G(g)] ) \\
    &= ε_{G^{\ab}}( [[g]] ) \\
    &= [g] \\
    &= \id_{G^{\ab}}( [g] ) \\
    &= (\id_F)_G( [g] )
  \end{align*}
  for every element $g$ of $G$, therefore $(εF ∘ Fη)_G = (\id_F)_G$ and thus $εF ∘ Fη = \id_F$.
  This shows the first triangle identity.
- For every abelian group $A$ we have
  \begin{align*}
    (Uε ∘ ηU)_A( a )
    = ε_A( η_A( a ) )
    = ε_A( [a] )
    = a
    = \id_A( a )
    = (\id_U)_A( a )
  \end{align*}
  for every element $a$ of $A$, therefore $(Uε ∘ ηU)_A = (\id_U)_A$, and thus $Uε ∘ ηU = \id_U$.
  This shows the second triangle identity.

We can also retrieve the natural bijection
$$
  Φ_{G, A} \colon \Hom_{\Ab}(G^{\ab}, A) \to \Hom_{Grp}(G, A)
$$
via $η$ and $ε$:
the bijection $Φ_{G, A}$ is given by $U(-) ∘ η_G = (-) ∘ η_G$, and its inverse is given by $ε_A ∘ F(-) = ε_A ∘ (-)^{\ab}$.